# Why is <select> different on my tablet and mobile phone?

Tags: html, web, mobile, browser, html-select

The tablet shows the drop-down list with a tap, just like on desktop.

The phone shows a list of options at the center of screen (it looks like a modal dialog).

For example, I tried [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select). I have Chrome 63.0.3239.83 on both devices. The tablet OS is Android 5.1.0 and the phone OS is Android 6.0.1.

What determines the difference? Could it be screen size or Android version?

Can I make the tablet show the options in the same way of my phone?

What about Android WebView? Do iOS tablet and phone also differ in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

select tag has user agent stylesheet for each browser. So it includes device and browser dependent styles and modes of operation